# Trouble displaying product tags as icons on Woocommerce product single page with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get my single product pages to display their product tags as icons that are assigned for each product tag using Advanced Custom Fields. I'm not particularly familiar with coding in php, but found a decent-looking code snippet online that I modified to suit my needs.

It looked like I was successful in my endeavor as my test product page indeed displayed its tags as icons. However, after a while, I realized that all my product pages displayed all my site's product tags -- no matter if they had been assigned to each product or not.

The below is what the code looks like at the moment. Any ideas on how to make it only pull product tags and icons assigned to each product?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
    'hide_empty' => false,
);

$i = 0;

$terms = get_terms( $args ); 

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $i++;
        $image = get_field('tag_icon', $term);
        ?>
        <div class="tag-icon tech-icon<? echo $i; ?>"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['url'] ?>">
            <span class="tag-name"><?php echo $term->name; ?></span>
        </a></div>
        <?php
    }  
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use get_the_terms() instead of get_terms(), get_the_terms() gets the terms of the post that you pass it, in this case product. [get_the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately changing get_terms ( $args ) to get_the_terms ( $args ) rendered the following error:
`Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function get_the_terms(),`

Comment: I think I figured it out!

I changed my original 

    `get_terms ( $args )`

to

    `get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ); `

And now I appear to only get the relevant product tags for each product.